# Android ListView Changing the Activity

Tags: android, listview, android-intent

my code:

```
    String[] category = {"CA", "Tax consultant", "MR", "Dance trainer"};
    ListAdapter categoryAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, category);
    ListView categoryListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.categoryListView);
    categoryListView.setAdapter(categoryAdapter);
```

what do I write to change the activity when a single item is clicked.even tell me what do I write in the new activity?

Comment: Do you want to open same activity when any item of listview is clicked?

Comment: Google any basic ListView tutorial (before asking questions).  You need to implement the onItemClicked method.

Comment: @apurva : no a different activity.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
categoryListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener
{
    @override
    public void onClick(int position)
    {
      startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), NewActivity.class));
    }
});
```

Comment: and what in the second activity?

Comment: do you want to send data in next activity?

Comment: no just open a blank activity. Eg: if a click "CA" it should open a blank activity

Comment: then just create a new activity  like : class NewActivity extends Acticity{  }